# What are good SaaS message queue systems?

Tags: web-services, message-queue, saas, data-synchronization, simperium

I'm considering using a message queue-like system as the backend for a web application that would provide for synchronization between a web server, mobile applications and browsers. Are there any existing turn-key SaaS solutions for this? This solution would preferably understand JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually had a particular startup in mind when I asked this question, but I couldn't for the life of me remember the name of the company. But now I remember: [Simperium](https://simperium.com/)

Additionally, [Firebase](http://www.firebase.com/) is similar and perhaps more mature than Simperium.

---

[Parse](http://www.parse.com) addresses a similar need (hosted backend) but it's RESTful so not addressing the same issue.